# C# -Fiinding available Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

Normally I heard that 25 threads are operating on ThreadPool.

When I execute the following :

```
namespace Examples.Delegates
{
    public delegate void InvokerDelegate();
    class Discussion
    {
       static void Main()
        {
            Discussion dis=new Discussion();
            InvokerDelegate MethodInvoker=dis.Foo;
            for(int i=1;i<=30;i++)
            {
                MethodInvoker.BeginInvoke(null,null);
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private void Foo()
        {
            int avlThreads, avlToAsynThreads;

            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads
            (out avlThreads,out avlToAsynThreads);

            string Message=string.
            Format("From ThreadPool :{0} ,Thread Id :{1},Free Threads :{2}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread,
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            avlThreads);
            Console.WriteLine(Message);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

The third argument of string "Message" (i.e) avlThreads  prints 490+ available threads.What
is the correction should i need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of threads in the thread pool has changed significantly over time.

- .NET 1.0/1.1/2.0/3.0: 25 worker threads per available processor. Not sure about I/O completion threads.
- .NET 3.5/4.0: 250 worker threads per available processor, and 1000 I/O completion threads.

(I have some vague memory that it was going to change for .NET 4.0, but the MSDN provisional documentation doesn't indicate that.)

So I suspect that you're running on a dual-processor system under .NET 3.5 or 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the correction you need to do is to [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx). The ThreadPool by default has 250 threads per processor. In .NET Framework 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 it was 25, in 3.5 it's 250.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx):

> The thread pool has a default size of
>   250 worker threads per available
>   processor

So if your machine is dual or quad core, it is normal that you get so many available threads.